# Segmentation Fault : Core Dumped while initializing large size arrays

Tags: c, arrays, fault

On linux, using gcc as the compiler, I get the infamous core dumped error.
**Global** Declaration:

```
#define MAX_N 10000  


double cost[MAX_N][MAX_N]={0};
int stack[MAX_N];
int visited[MAX_N];
```

Where the error occurs (goes away once I comment out these lines):

```
for(q=0;q<5;++q) 
    {
        visited[q]=0;
        stack[q]=0;
    }
```

This piece of code lies inside a function which gets called 10,000+ number of times. So every time the function is called, this initalisation needs to be done! I've tried using memset, but that too does not seem to help!

Comment: that isn't necessarily where the error occurs.. commenting out the lines might change something that causes some other code to crash

Comment: 10000 is not a large size. Obviously, the error is somewhere else. It is normal with such kind of errors, to trigger faults far away from the origin.

Comment: How do I trace where exactly the error occurs then?

Comment: This part of the code isn't the problem, because everything is properly initialized. Since you already have a core dump, you can use it with [gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) and the executable compiled `-g` to get a stack trace: `gdb /path/to/exe /path/to/core` and then do `bt`.

Comment: To summarize. The error is not in the code, you've provided. I would suggest to use valgrind tool, to detect the actual failure point. You can search SO or the web, or use valgrind documentation to learn how to detected segfaults with it.

Comment: Post a complete program that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My Guess:

Despite what @ivg says, 10000 is actually a large size. Your declaration will take at least 760Mb, and this can easily touch same of your hard limits, especially when increasing the stack size at runtime (thing that you normally do while calling functions inside functions).

I would try to move that declaration it the heap memory space (that is calling malloc/free).

Answer (score 1):

If those arrays are declared at file scope, they have static storage duration and are stored in the `.bss` segment.

If those arrays are declared at local scope, they are stored on the stack.

In either case, you are using extreme amounts of memory which most likely exceeds the maximum limit of the `.bss` or stack on your given system.

Assuming `sizeof(double) == 8` and `sizeof(int) == 4`, then you have allocated

```
(8 * 10000 * 10000) + (4 * 10000) + (4 * 10000) = 800,080,000 bytes
```

Roughly 780Mb of space.

Large amounts of memory like this should be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a stack overflow. Often this has no sensible symptoms, just bizarre crashes. The most obvious thing to try is to make your large arrays be `static`, or use dynamic allocation instead.

Comment: From what we can see in the code posted, the arrays already have static storage duration.

Comment: He said this piece of code appears inside a function.

Comment: I don't think it's clear whether or not the arrays were declared inside the function, or just the loop snippet. At any rate, `static` will not solve the problem, just move it elsewhere. Dynamic allocation is the only correct solution.